# Counting: Difference between two questions

Tags: combinatorics

There are two questions which seem very similar to me but they use a totally different answer and i cant understand why. Could you clarify for me please?

**Question 1**
there are 12 people and 7 books. how many ways can you distribute the 7 books among the 12 people if no person is to receive more than 1 book.

**answer:**
to distribute book 1, there are 12 people
book 2: 11 people 
book 3: 10 people 
...
book 7: 6 people
so the answer is $12*11*10*9*8*7*6$

**Question 2** In how many ways can $k$ elements be chosen from an $n-element$ set $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n\}$
**answer**
$C^n_k$

Now my confusion is; why is the answer to question 2 "n choose k". why isn't it similar to question 1 where to choose the first element you have $n$ choices, then $(n-1)$ choices then $(n-2)$ and so on so forth leading to an answer of $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)...(1)$

I hope you can see where my confusion is arising...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know the formula for $C^{n}_{k}$? You assume something about the people in the first problem that you do not about elements you choose in the second. That is, to be more precise, you treat people as distinct in the first problem, but in the second problem, it is as if you are distributing $k$ books to $n$ IDENTICAL people.

Comment: ok ok ok that makes sense now after having a look at the formula. I  see where the division of k! comes from in the "n chose k" formula (identical elements).  You can make your answer official and ill mark it.

Comment: Glad you understand! No need friend.

Comment: In the book problem, we could instead have first chosen the people who will receive a book. In your notation, that can be done in $C_7^{12}$ ways. Then we multiply by $7!$ because which person receives which book matters.